# map map return flat array in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to have array of arrays.

My code:

```
image_data = $('.post-entry').map(function() {
    return $(this).find('img').map(function() {
      var self = $(this);
      return {
        big: self.hasClass('big') || self.hasClass('medium'),
        offset: self.offset(),
        width: self.width(),
        height: self.height()
      };
    }).get();
  }).get();
```

but when I have two post-entry elements and each have 4 images I have array of 8 images. How can I get array of two elements of 4 elements each? Why I got flat array?

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/WxKrw/)

Comment: Interesting...seems like it should work. Could you make a fiddle (swap images out for something else)?

Comment: try to switch the order of the call of your functions, first img.map then .post-entry.map ...

Comment: @Oliboy50 I can't because .post-entry is a parent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because the documentation for [map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) says (emphasis mine):

> The function can return an individual data item *or an array of data
>   items* to be inserted into the resulting set. *If an array is returned,
>   the elements inside the array are inserted into the set*.

Therefore, `map()` flattens the arrays you return, and this behavior is by design.

Try wrapping these arrays into another array, as I believe `map()` only flattens once:

```
image_data = $('.post-entry').map(function() {
    return [
        $(this).find('img').map(function() {
            var self = $(this);
            return {
                big: self.hasClass('big') || self.hasClass('medium'),
                offset: self.offset(),
                width: self.width(),
                height: self.height()
            };
        }).get()
    ];
}).get();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create an empty array, and then add an index for each `post-entry`, containing the `img` objects. I suspect there could be a better way to do this, though:

```
var image_data = [];
$('.post-entry').each(function(i) {

  image_data[i] = $(this).find('img').map(function() {
    var self = $(this);
    return {
      big: self.hasClass('big') || self.hasClass('medium'),
      offset: self.offset(),
      width: self.width(),
      height: self.height()
    };
  }).get(); 

});
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YhHat/5/)