# jQuery .toArray() not working as expected inside .map()

Tags: jquery

I'm having a hard time understanding the behaviour of jQuery's `.toArray()` in this scenario.

I have 2 `<table>`, one for "Participants" and one for "Winners".
I want to extract some data from these tables using jQuery.

I use 2 `.map()` functions to transform the contents of the table into arrays/objects, have a look at the code:

### HTML:

```
<h2>Participants</h2>
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>01</td>
      <td>Andrew</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>02</td>
      <td>Julian</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>03</td>
      <td>Matt</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>04</td>
      <td>Sarah</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<h2>Winners</h2>
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>01</td>
      <td>Andrew</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>04</td>
      <td>Sarah</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

### JavaScript:

```
const result = $('table')
  .map((i, table) => {
    return $(table)
      .find('tbody tr')
      .map((j, row) => {
        const $row = $(row);

        return {
          number: $row.find('td:nth-child(1)').text(),
          name: $row.find('td:nth-child(2)').text(),
        };
      })
      .toArray(); // [1]
  })
  .toArray();

console.log(result);
```

**[1]** Without the `.toArray()` I get an array with 2 jQuery objects, one for each table. (Great!)
But when I add `.toArray()` all of a sudden it returns a single array with all the objects inside, why?
Where's the separation the was there before?!

### Expected output:

```
[
  [
    {number: "01", name: "Andrew"},
    {number: "02", name: "Julian"},
    {number: "03", name: "Matt"},
    {number: "04", name: "Sarah"}
  ],
  [
    {number: "01", name: "Andrew"},
    {number: "04", name: "Sarah"}
  ]
]
```

### Actual output:

```
[
  {number: "01", name: "Andrew"},
  {number: "02", name: "Julian"},
  {number: "03", name: "Matt"},
  {number: "04", name: "Sarah"},
  {number: "01", name: "Andrew"},
  {number: "04", name: "Sarah"}
]
```

I made a jsfiddle so you can see for yourself: https://jsfiddle.net/93cLyq6h/22/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is actually not with `.toArray()` but with jquery's `.map()`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19160264/map-map-return-flat-array-in-jquery) is another answer explaining this, but when the [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) parameter function returns an array, each element is inserted into the set rather than the array itself. So your outer `.map()` flattens the two arrays into one.

> If an array is returned, the elements inside the array are inserted into the set.

[Is there a jQuery map utility that doesn't automically flatten?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703355/is-there-a-jquery-map-utility-that-doesnt-automically-flatten) here is something that should help you get what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i really don't understand the design decision behind this behaviour, but at least now i know about it!

Answer (score 0):

The results of the `$.fn.map` call needs to be wrapped in square brackets `[ ... ]`.

```js
const result = $('table')
  .map((i, table) => [
    $(table)
      .find('tbody tr')
      .map((j, row) => [{
        number: $(row).find('td:nth-child(1)').text(),
        name: $(row).find('td:nth-child(2)').text(),
      }]).toArray()
  ]).toArray();

// Format results...
console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2)
  .replace(/\{\n\s+"/g, '{ "')
  .replace(/,\n\s+"/g, ', ')
  .replace(/"\n\s+\}/g, '" }'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Participants</h2>
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>01</td>
      <td>Andrew</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>02</td>
      <td>Julian</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>03</td>
      <td>Matt</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>04</td>
      <td>Sarah</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<h2>Winners</h2>
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>01</td>
      <td>Andrew</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>04</td>
      <td>Sarah</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```